# Using hibernate to get 2 objects which both are linked with a logical foreign key (reference key)

Tags: hibernate

I am new to hibernate and my tables are as follows:

Tb_User

- UserId (PK)
- UserFirstName
- UserLastName
- UserLogin
- UserPwd

Tb_Order

- OrderId (PK)
- UserId (Logical FK)
- OrderDate
- OrderRemarks

My Dao class's function:

```
public List<TbOrder> getUserOrdering(TbOrder tbOrder) throws Exception{
    Criteria _criteria = getSession().createCriteria(TbOrder.class);

    if(tbOrder.getUserId() != null)
        _criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("UserId", tbOrder.getUserId()));
    return (List<TbOrder>) _criteria.list();    
}
```

My Entity class:

```
class TbOrder {
    Long orderId;
    Long userId;

    public TbOrder(){

    }
    public TbOrder(Long orderId, Long userId){
        this.orderId = orderId;
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public Long getOrderId() {
        return orderId;
    }
    public void setOrderId(Long orderId) {
        this.orderId = orderId;
    }
    public Long getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }
    public void setUserId(Long userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }
}

class TbUser{
    private Long userId;
    private String userFirstName;
    private String userLastName;
    private String userLogin;
    private String userPwd;

    public TbUser() {

    }

    public TbUser(Long userId, String userFirstName, String userLastName,
            String userLogin, String userPwd) {
        this.userId = userId;
        this.userFirstName = userFirstName;
        this.userLastName = userLastName;
        this.userLogin = userLogin;
        this.userPwd = userPwd;
    }

    public Long getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(Long userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public String getUserFirstName() {
        return userFirstName;
    }

    public void setUserFirstName(String userFirstName) {
        this.userFirstName = userFirstName;
    }

    public String getUserLastName() {
        return userLastName;
    }

    public void setUserLastName(String userLastName) {
        this.userLastName = userLastName;
    }

    public String getUserLogin() {
        return userLogin;
    }

    public void setUserLogin(String userLogin) {
        this.userLogin = userLogin;
    }

    public String getUserPwd() {
        return userPwd;
    }

    public void setUserPwd(String userPwd) {
        this.userPwd = userPwd;
    }
}
```

It is supposed that Tb_Order.UserId should be set as a foreign key which link to Tb_User, but for some reasons, I can't do so.

However, here is my sitruation, I want to get the user's first name and last name who has placed the order with id=1001, and also the order's date and remarks. Normally, while I was googling for a while, someone tells me I can try something like `id.userid` to get Tb_User object, however, I din't get any Id class generated by hibernate and it is supposed to be. So, please advice me what is the best way to get both order and user information? Thanks!

Comment: Your question is very confusing. What are you trying to achieve. What's the code and mapping of these two entities?

Comment: I have modified my question and adding 2 more columns to Tb_Order. Basically I want to join these 2 tables and get the result within one object.

Comment: What's the code and mapping of these two entities?

Comment: Sorry I am not sure what you are asking for. Tb_Order.UserId is the logical foreign key to Tb_User.UserId. What do you mean the code? The java code I have posted above, isn't it?

Comment: The Java code of your **entities**. I.e. the code of the `TbOrder` and `TbUser` class.

Comment: As you said, I have added the entity classes.

Comment: There is no mapping annotation in there. And you missed a fundamental aspect of Hibernate: associations between entities. You need a OneToMany/ManyToOne association between the entities. You should not have the ID of the user in Order, but a reference to the User itself. Read the documentation.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35199/discussion-between-steve-lam-and-jb-nizet)

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying your Dao class's function like this:

```
public List <Tb_User>   getUserOrdering(TbOrder tbOrder) throws Exception{
    Criteria _criteria = getSession().createCriteria(Tb_User.class);

    if(tbOrder.getUserId() != null)
        _criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("UserId", tbOrder.getUserId()));
    return (List<Tb_User>) _criteria.list();    
}
```

The `List <Tb_User>` which you will get, iterate it and from the list of Tb_User objects you can get the user's first name and last name using your getter methods.

NOTE: I am assuming **TbOrder tbOrder** object which you are passing has the required UserId inside it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have modified my question, and I would like to retrieve Tb_Order.OrderDate and Tb_Order.OrderRemarks too, so I think list<Tb_User> is not enough for my situation.